# Visualforce 'Rendered ' parameter not recognising field

Tags: visualforce, error, rendered

I'm trying to display some Visualforce if a checkbox = True. Here is my code snippet:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="warning" rendered="{!(Innovation__c.Show_Warning__c)}"> 
    <h1 color="red"> WARNING </h1>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Unknown property 'Innovation__c.Show_Warning__c' referenced in DisplayRejectionWarning
```

The API names are correct, I've checked a billion times. Why is it not recognising the field?

Comment: Are you using a standard controller in your page?

Comment: I believe your code is wrong.consider  Innovation__c is child and show_warning_c is parent.if you write that code it wont work . if you refering parentid field here  rendered="{!Innovation__c.Show_Warning__r.checkbox==true}" something like this.can you plz post the code. here checkbox is showwarning object field

Comment: If you are using a custom controller, make sure it is public. By default it is private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggested solutions.

I actually managed to come right by adding the controlling object (Innovation__c) in the  tag. Now its recognising the merge field, "Innovation__c.Show_Warning__c".

Answer (score 1):

You should create a property for the Custom Object in your controller before referencing it in the Visualforce page.

```
public Innovation__c inv {get; set;}
```

After creating the property, you can use it in VF page as below:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="warning" rendered="{!(inv.Show_Warning__c)}"> 
    <h1 color="red"> WARNING </h1>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Make sure you add the controller in the VF Page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Innovation__c.Show_Warning__c` in a rendered condition only if you are using StandardController on that Visualforce page as "Innovation__c".  Most likely you are using a custom controller/extension.

In that case, your object needs to be created as a property in your controller.

```
public Innovation__c Innovation {get; set;}
```

Then you can use `Innovation.Show_Warning__c` in your rendering conditions.